# Retrieve SSL certificate fields in the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ssl-certificate, nsurl

Our application communicates with server over HTTPS. We want to re-verify the SSL certificate fields on the client side. e.g. I want to verify the CN field of the SSL certificate issues from the server during HTTPS connection. Is there way to retrieve fields information in the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge()`?

Comment: The web server sends a certificate to the client?  That doesn't seem right to me.  Can you point me to some docs on that please?

Answer (score 0):

As a refresher of how the steps of SSL are performed can be found here http://www.symantec.com/theme.jsp?themeid=how-ssl-works

@Ramesh

(for the function used, please have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html

proceed like this

- SecTrustRef tR = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
- call SecTrustEvaluate()
- call SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex() with index 0 then you can use OpenSSL to do any further validation