# How to verify server side certificate using NSURLConection on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, ssl, nsurlconnection, osx-snow-leopard

Problem: the SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex() API is not working on OSX 10.6 (works perfectly fine on 10.7 and above).

Details:

It seems that if I am called from within the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge() delegate method, there is a fairly straightforward method to do it on 10.7 and 10.8 (incl. iOS) using the convenient SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex() API.
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784251/retrieve-ssl-certificate-fields-in-the-didreceiveauthenticationchallenge?answertab=active#tab-top) here on this site.

This specific method works fine on 10.7 and above but on 10.6 the SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex() function is not working and returns a null.

You can see that other guys already stumbled accross this here: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/curl/lib/curl_darwinssl.c

So what is the correct method for obtaining the host certificate and the issuer certificate on 10.6? Is there an alternative method I can use while still using the NSURLConnection API?

Thanks a lot!